# PF temporary reroute to different IP

Tags: freebsd, pf

I have a FreeBSD host that serves as an entry point to additional systems on an internal network. As such I have `pf` configured to redirect incoming traffic on certain ports (say, port 5000) to the host local address on one of the jails running a network service on that machine. This looks like this:

```
---port 5000--->[Main host]
                     |
                     |---port 5000--->[Machine A]
                     |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[Machine B]
```

The redirection is performed by the PF rule:

```
rdr pass on egress proto tcp from any to $IP port 5000 -> $MACHINE_A_IP
```

This is the state I almost always want, and that is what is configured by default. However, I'd like to sometimes *temporarily* redirect port 5000 to the Machine B, like this:

```
---port 5000--->[Main host]
                     |
                     |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[Machine A]
                     |---port 5000--->[Machine B]
```

I've tried setting up PF anchors to facilitate this, but as I'm new to PF I find it hard to parse documentation to cover this use case.

How do I issue dynamic PF rules on the main host to temporarily redirect 5000 from Machine A to Machine B?

Comment: How are you expecting to trigger the switchover? If its manual maintenance,  just keep 2 variables & comment-out one, and reload the config. Otherwise you may want to look at  [relayd(8)](http://bsd.plumbing/) [(man)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=relayd&sektion=8)as an automatic failover if A is down

Comment: I'd expect to do so from either a shell on the machine or a cronjob. It's not an automatic failover situation, they are in fact different services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to achieve this is to use table as a target for redirection. You can change content of table without reloading pf using `pfctl`. Just be aware that existing firewall states will keep forwarding traffic to the old host until tcp streams are closed or udp "streams" timeout.

Comment: I have since found another way to accomplish this problem, and cannot properly check this any more unfortunately. I'll accept this answer as the correct one if someone else can confirm this is the proper way of doing it! Thank you for the answer.